# Should I use 'Combo', 'Set' or 'Assortment'?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

In the context of common hardware items, for instance:

- 2 screws
- 2 bolts

If these are sold in a single packaged product, should it be called a 'fastener combo', 'fastener set' or 'fastener assortment'? Does the same rule apply if describing the price? For instance, is it called a 'combo price', 'set price' or 'assortment price'? If the same item is sold singly, should I describe it as '1 screw at normal price' or 'original price'? Thank you.

Comment: spelling: `fastener`.

Comment: I'd expect "set" or "kit". It depends if the user would be expected to use all the parts together or not. "Combined price" and "individual price" would be clear; but check your local hardware store/website to see what they use. "Combo" is more colloquial, although it's often used by e.g. fast food restaurants for a "meal deal".

Comment: None of those. combo/set/assortment are applied to different realities. combo does not apply to screws and bolts. An assortment of screws and bolts are many of them. And set is 2 of something. So...

Comment: I would expect a `set` to be a collection of fasteners used for completing a specific task, whereas an `assortment` would be a collection of different sizes, etc. for general use. `Combo` sounds odd to me in this context, I wouldn't know quite which to expect. Probably same as `assortment`.

Comment: Thank you. I was not expected all the parts to be used together. So I can use none of these words...Maybe I should simply say 'screws and bolts'.

Comment: If they're not to be used together, why are they sold as a group?

Comment: It's kinda like a bulk purchase. Each item's unit price is cheaper. Some parts might be used together but some parts might not.

Answer (score 1):

Everything but "assortment" is acceptable.

"Set" is best, perhaps because combo sounds like you're trying to sell me fast food or a great deal when I am buying something bland.